# How tdo you add an unallocated space partition to your kali linux partition? (Kali linux dual booted with windows 10)

Tags: kali-linux, hard-disk, disk

I am currently using Kali linux as a dual boot with windows 10. I cannot figure out how to allocate my Kali linux OS unallocated space that I have on one of my drives without reinstalling.

I have only just set up Kali linux as a dual boot with windows on my laptop and have only allocated it 20GB. I have 90GB of unallocated space which I would also like to add to it.

At the moment the partition that I have allocated for my kali linux is not sitting adjacent to my unallocated space partition. I have used NIUBI with windows to try move them together but it has not worked. I have also used gparted in my Kali Linux to try fix it but it has not been successful. I don't know if it has something to do with the file system as my kali linux partition is ext4 and the unallocated space partition is FAT32.

Im unsure how this can be fixed.

Comment: You mention the extra partition as unallocated yet you say it is formatted. Could you please update your post with the output of `lsblk` to give users a better idea of what your partitioning scheme is? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to prepare all your partitions before you decide to do a hard install, unfortunately you have to wipe your kali install, merge the two partitions, then reinstall on that new partition.